# WPF MenuItem.CommandTarget

Tags: wpf, binding, command, menuitem

Does anybody know what the CommandTarget property on a MenuItem can be used for? [The documentation says the following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommandsource.commandtarget.aspx):

> When used with a RoutedCommand, the command target is the object on
>   which the Executed and CanExecute events are raised. If the
>   CommandTarget property is not set, the element with keyboard focus
>   will be used as the target.

However, at runtime, the value of CommandTarget is nowhere to be seen in the Execute handler for the command. sender is the window the CommandBinding belongs to. ExecutedRoutedEventArgs is full of references to distant ancestors of the menu item.

The goal here is to implement a command which is executed from a variety of different context menus on a variety of different grids, lists, whatever -- they all contain items which support a particular interface. Their context menus differ, but have some commands in common. The common commands use the same Executed and CanExecute handlers regardless of what you click on, because the "Foo" command does "Foo". The handlers figure out what the selected item is for whatever grid/list you clicked on, try to cast it to an interface, and do something with it if it's got that interface (if the interface consumed by a given command isn't supported by the item, that command is disabled). If I get the ContextMenu or MenuItem as sender, I can get the PlacementTarget and I know what the user clicked on, but that only works if I define the CommandBinding in the XAML definition of the ContextMenu -- which means copy'n'pasting that whole block of XAML in every ContextMenu where the command is used, and redefining the handlers in every one of those view classes. That's not a mess I want to maintain.

It seems like this is a case where there's no language-independent reason to write those handlers more than once, or associate each one with a given command more than once. But as far as I can tell, it appears that XAML wants you to bind the handlers and the target all together. Can you bind the handlers once and then sneak in a different target?

UPDATE: I resolved this by putting the commands in a static Command class, the handlers in a non-static class (the main view, not that it matters), and writing a static Command.GetCommandBinding(command) method which instantiates and returns a CommandBinding for the command you pass in. So if I want to use command Foo on grid Bar, in the constructor for the view where Bar lives I just call this:

```
Bar.CommandBindings.Add(Commands.GetCommandBinding(Commands.Foo));
```

Bar is then passed as the sender for the Executed and CanExecute events on the command when it is assigned to the Command property of a MenuItem belonging to Bar's ContextMenu.

Can't do the binding in XAML because the handlers have to be members of the View class. It seems odd that the designers put this much work into helping us reuse the NAMES of commands while making it so painful to reuse the actual, like CODE for the command, but whatever. It's not the dumbest thing Microsoft ever did, and most of the rest of XAML is pretty great (IMHO).

Another solution: Define menu items as resources independently of context menus, and reuse the whole menu items. This is in Resources.xaml, which I can include in other XAML files as a merged dictionary. The event handlers are in Resources.cs. Consumers can use GridContextMenu, or insert CtxMenuItem_EmailDocument into their own context menus the same way.

```
<MenuItem Command="{x:Static vw:Commands.EmailDocument}" 
        x:Key="CtxMenuItem_EmailDocument">
    <MenuItem.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static vw:Commands.EmailDocument}"
                        Executed="EmailDocument_Executed"
                        CanExecute="EmailDocument_CanExecute"
                        />
    </MenuItem.CommandBindings>
</MenuItem>

<ContextMenu x:Key="GridContextMenu" x:Shared="true">
    <!-- other items -->
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="CtxMenuItem_EmailDocument" />
    <!-- other items -->
</ContextMenu>
```

CommandTarget seems to exhibit completely different behavior on a Button. Either that, or CommandBindings behave completely differently if they're defined in separate file, or as a resource, or... whatever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **CommandTarget** is the element on which the CommandManager class will start the routing of the CanExecute and Execute events when the associated Command is a RoutedCommand. So it is not really going to show up as any of the parameters of the event args for the CanExecute/Execute - actually it may be the **OriginalSource** but I wouldn't rely on that because if the CommandManager reroutes the command (because it enters a new **FocusScope** as it traverses up the tree) then it will reroute and the OriginalSource for the eventargs for rerouted event will then be that element that it rerouted to.

Typically you do not set the CommandTarget for RoutedCommands that can be handled by multiple element types - e.g. the ApplicationCommands like Cut/Copy/Paste where you want the control the end user is interacting with to receive and respond to the command. However if you have a case where regardless of what element the end user has focused, you want to make sure that the RoutedCommand that you have set for the Command property of that ICommandSource (the MenuItem in this case) is executed on a specific element instance then you would set the CommandTarget to that element (typically using an ElementName Binding).

**Edit:**
Since you have changed the question, I'll augment my answer. If you want to handle the CanExecute and Execute for certain RoutedCommands on particular class types then what you would want to do is to use the CommandManager class - specifically it's [RegisterClassCommandBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.registerclasscommandbinding.aspx) method - to register your global Execute/CanExecute handler for your specific RoutedCommands.

Comment: It's definitely not the OriginalSource in my case. What does it mean when you say "the RoutedCommand... executed on a specific instance"? What does "executed on" mean? Is there any way to find out at runtime what control a command is being "executed on"? That's the question I'm asking.

Comment: CommandTarget is simply the element that is passed to the **Execute** and **CanExecute** methods of the **RoutedCommand** for the _inputElement_ parameter. For ButtonBase/MenuItem they will pass themselves if CommandTarget is null. Inside RoutedCommand, if the target is null it would use the **Keyboard.FocusedElement**. That then calls RaiseEvent for the PreviewExecuted and Executed events for that element. So to answer the specific question - CommandTarget is used to specify the element whose RaiseEvent method is invoked for those RoutedCommand events.

Comment: OK, I'm handling the Executed/CanExecute events on the binding, so it sounds like CommandTarget isn't used in that case? Or if it is used, it doesn't make any difference where RaiseEvent is called.

Comment: Again **CommandTarget** really just controls where the routing starts (or in the case of preview/tunnel events ends). It sounds like for your case you really don't need to be setting CommandTarget. You just want to be able to centralize handling the CanExecute/Execute for your commands for certain elements types and that would be done using **RegisterClassCommandBinding** as I mentioned in my update to the answer.

Comment: If routing has no effects on anything my code can interact with, it and its beginning and end points are metaphysical concepts that I shouldn't be spending company time on. The ghost in the machine doesn't write us any checks. RegisterClassCommandBinding sounds interesting but it's effectively undocumented[1]. I've got a kludge that works, so I'll stick with that. Again, thanks. [1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.registerclasscommandbinding(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I didn't saying that routing has no effect. As with any routed event, an element is needed as the starting pt. That is all that CommandTarget is meant to control and when unspecified the cmd src (button/menuitem) is used. Obviously the element used as a starting pt has an effect - it controls through which elements the routing of the events will occur. However that is not what your updated question is about. RegisterClassCommandBinding while with limited documented is used quite a lot. If you use reflector you will see that basically any custom control which uses routed commands uses this.

Comment: RegisterClassCommandBinding is meant to provide a way to register a CommandBinding for a given command for a given control class. So you can register that when the FooCommand is raised for a DataGrid, that your ExecutedRoutedEventHandler and CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler will be invoked regardless of where the control is defined and without you having to add a CommandBinding to the CommandBindings of each control instance. If you wanted you could even define an attached property that you looked at within those handlers to effectively allow a way to opt out of the handling via xaml.

Comment: I know you didn't say routing has no effect. What I'm telling you is that it has no effect on the parameters passed to the event handlers of a CommandBinding, in any case I've yet seen. Anyhow, looking back, my original question was "What does CommandTarget do?", and you answered that. I don't have the background necessary to parse the answer, but an answer is what it is. Probably. Anyway, I feel bad wasting all your time. You've been very patient.

Comment: OMG, attached properties, I always forget about those. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Everything AndrewS has written is correct, I just want to add that the CommandTarget will be the **sender** of the Executed / CanExecute events. In order to be able to handle the command, the CommandTarget needs a CommandBinding for the Command in question.

Minimum example:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Button Command="Open" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=TestTextBox}">Open</Button>
    <TextBox x:Name="TestTextBox">
        <TextBox.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding Command="Open" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed"/>
        </TextBox.CommandBindings>
    </TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: The sender of those events is in my experience the owner of the CommandBindings collection where the CommandBinding resides, regardless of whether CommandTarget is defined as that, or something else, or nothing at all. Based on what I've seen, I would expect your example to work identically if you removed the CommandTarget attribute from Button.

Comment: Well, you should have tried it... without the CommandTarget, the Button will be disabled, since the TextBox is not in a place where it could receive routed commands from the Button.

Comment: Note that I hedged. I'll give it a shot. Maybe buttons are different.

Comment: OK, I tested it, and it never calls the CanExecute handler (I added one) unless there's a CommandTarget, and is disabled without the CommandTarget. This bears no resemblance to anything I've seen with MenuItems. That's just sad. It's an event handler mechanism. That's a well-understood problem. It's been solved dozens of times. There's no excuse for anything this arcane.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, the `CommandTarget`, in the context of a `MenuItem`, sets the `OriginalSource` property on `ExecutedRoutedEventArgs` received by the `Executed` and `CanExecute` handlers.

So the "Target" is the "Source"
(Much in the same way that a camel is a horse designed by a committee)

The `Sender`, as stated by @EdPlunket, is the site of the command bindings (as is `e.Source` too actually).

So, to answer the original question, the `CommandTarget` of a `MenuItem` is passed as a reference, to the `Executed` and `CanExecute` handlers of a command, on the event args (`ExecutedRoutedEventArgs` and `CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs`) on their `OriginalSource` property.  So you can use that reference to do whatever you like on the target.

### Working Example

The `CommandTarget` of the `MenuItem` is controlled by the ComboBox selection

MainWindow.xaml

```
<Window x:Class="CommandTarget.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommandTarget"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="200" Width="400">

    <StackPanel x:Name="RootPanel">

        <StackPanel.CommandBindings>
            <CommandBinding x:Name="Pause" Command="Pause"
                            Executed="{x:Static local:MainWindow.OnButtonPause}"
                            CanExecute="{x:Static local:MainWindow.OnPauseCanExecute}" />
        </StackPanel.CommandBindings>

        <DockPanel>

            <Menu DockPanel.Dock="Top" >
                <MenuItem Header="Click Me" x:Name="Emitter"
                          Command="Pause"
                          CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=Button2}" />
            </Menu>

        </DockPanel>

        <StackPanel Name="Buttons">

            <ToggleButton x:Name="Button1" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Content="Button1" />
            <ToggleButton x:Name="Button2" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Content="Button2" />

        </StackPanel>

    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace CommandTarget
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        //PAUSE COMMAND
        // Static, binding callbacks

        // Executed
        public static ExecutedRoutedEventHandler
            OnButtonPause = (sender, e) =>
            {
                e.Handled = ButtonPauseTarget(e, delegate(ToggleButton target)
                {
                    if (!target.IsEnabled) return false;
                    var flag = target.IsChecked ?? false;
                    target.IsChecked = !flag;
                    return true;
                });
            };

        // CanExecute
        public static CanExecuteRoutedEventHandler
            OnPauseCanExecute = (sender, e) => { e.CanExecute = true; };

        // helper to extract the target from the event args
        private static bool ButtonPauseTarget (RoutedEventArgs e,
            Func<ToggleButton, bool> ex)
        {
            var target = e.OriginalSource as ToggleButton;
            if (target == null) return false;
            var handled = ex(target);

            return handled;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: The Pause command is just a random choice, any of the commands supported by the source element, that is not used by any other  will do.

[More complete example](https://github.com/cool-blue-WPF/Examples/tree/bound-in-xaml)

Comment: Thank you, that does work with `Button`. However I find it hard to determine if the principle is exactly the same for `MenuItem`: I wrote some test code and found that with a `MenuItem` this didn't quite work. With your `CommandBinding`, `MenuItem` with `Command="Play"` is never enabled. The `MenuItem` has the correct command with the correct `Execute` handler, but `CanExecute` is never called. Also, with `<MenuItem x:Name="MI" CommandTarget="{Binding ElementName=Foo}" />`, `MI.CommandTarget` is `null`. `Foo` does exist.

Comment: Problem with `MenuItem.CommandTarget` is "System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'ElementName=Foo'. BindingExpression:(no path); DataItem=null; target element" -- out of the visual tree perhaps

Comment: @EdPlunkett Yes, I was a bit rushed and didn't realise that the `MenuItem` is a little more fussy regarding `CanExecute`.  It can't be omitted but can as simple as `return true;`.  For my own learning, I redid it using a `MenuItem` control to prove the concept.